# If the id's from two arrays of objects match return needed value from certain key value pair

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, conditional-statements, jsx

```
const arr1 = [1,2,3,4];
const arr2  = [1,2];

const arr11 = [{_id: 1, etc: "whatever"},{_id: 2, etc: "whatever"},{_id: 3, etc: "whatever"},{_id: 4, etc: "whatever"}];
const arr22  = [{_id: 1, toPrint: 3.5},{_id: 2, toPrint: 5.7}];

arr1.filter(item1 => 
arr2.includes(item1)  ? console.log(item1) :  console.log("N/A")
)
```

expected result between arr1 and arr2 (this works fine):
1
2
N/A
N/A 
expected result between arr11 and arr22 (need solution jsx compatible):
3.5
5.7
N/A
N/A
https://playcode.io/662468/
Note: if arr11 has no corresponding id in arr22 return "N\A"

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.find`

```js
const arr11 = [
  { _id: 1, etc: "whatever" },
  { _id: 2, etc: "whatever" },
  { _id: 3, etc: "whatever" },
  { _id: 4, etc: "whatever" },
]
const arr22 = [
  { _id: 1, toPrint: 3.5 },
  { _id: 2, toPrint: 5.7 },
]

arr11.forEach((item1) => {
  const item2 = arr22.find((item2) => item2._id === item1._id)
  console.log(item2 ? item2.toPrint : "N/A")
})
```

Comment: wow, thanks a lot!  this works great! Nice and clean solution. ty